# CSS height cases

Tags: css

I created a page where the content is dynamically loaded with ajax. I set the background color of the loaded content to be a transparent white. When the content does not fill the entire page I want the background to extend to the bottom of the page minux 20px as with this css:

```
#content {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    position:absolute;
    top: 20px; left: 380px; bottom: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

when the content extends PAST the bottom of the page I want the background to extend with it AND leave a 20 px margin underneath the background. Usually I would use display: block; to accomplish this but that overrides the bottom: 20px; rule. How do I get the css to work the way I want in both situations?

Comment: Use javascript to update the height of the div each time you make the call to ajax.

Comment: i prefer not to use javascript for something that is clearly style related.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead:

```
#content {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 800px; /* height of the window */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}​
```

You may want to consider using jQuery to set the min-height to equal the user's window height.

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
$("#content").height(windowHeight);
```

Comment: I want a min-height relative to the users screen size so setting an absolute min-height won't work. I would rather not use jquery for something that it clearly style related (separation of tasks and all that).

Comment: There is always an issue in combining % with pixels in css (height: 100% - 20px). It is probably solvable but most likely requires additional html markup and kind of depends on why those 20px are there. This is why you probably only get jQuery/js suggestions. Maybe you could post an example and tell us how you want it to look, that way you open up a whole other set of possibilities you might not have considered (and we can't, as we do not know how the final product is supposed to look like).

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm is hard to understand your needs without having a fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net :| From what you are saying seems to be a body issue. You can set a "body class"(create a container div in which you add all your content with width and height 100%) for loaded section for which you can set a background and only for your content that does not fill all section you can diplay in a div content for which also apply another background color and set what margin-bottom you want.
Cheers.